# Как декодируется информация из формы (method=post) в Perl-скрипте?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Есть хтмл-форма:

```
<form method=post action='../testing.cgi'>
        <label> Имя: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
        <input id='name' name='name' type='text'> </label>
        <br><label>Пароль: <input id='pass' name='pass' type='password'> </label>

        <br>Пол: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <select id='selectsex' name=sex[]>
        <option value='мужской'>мужской</option>
        <option value='женский'>женский</option>
        </select>

        <br>Возраст: 
        <br><input type='radio' name='age' value='18'> 18
        <br><input type='radio' name='age' value='19'> 19
        <br><input type='radio' name='age' value='20'> 20

        <br>Какие языки вы знаете?
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='english'> Английский
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='russian'> Русский
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='ukrainian'> Украинский
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='polish'> Польский
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='german'> Немецкий
        <br><input type='checkbox' name='languages[]' value='french'> Французкий

        <br><br>Можете добавить некоторый комментарий, если хотите:<br>
        <textarea name='textarea' placeholder='Hello. My name is Tom Riddle...'></textarea>

        <br><button id='send'>Отправить</button>
    </form>
```

И Perl-скрипт, декодирующий информацию из формы (только кириллицу, ибо латиницу воспроизводит адекватно), как я полагаю, вот этой строкой (взято из примеров в гугле):

`$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;`

Собсно говоря, поясните, что здесь происходит?
Как я понимаю, текущее значение переменнoй $value сравнивается на соответствие заданному шаблону регэкспа, после чего... делится на рез-ат функции pack?? wtf? Хочу **понять**

И ещё вопрос, когда я вывожу атрибут **name** элемента формы в perl-скрипте, то, если там присутствовали квадратные скобки, получаю пакость: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как от неё избавиться и выводить реальное название?

Comment: Приведенная вами строка как раз должна в $value все %NN заменить на символы им соответствующие. Функция pack с параметром 'C'  делает как раз символы с тем кодом который дали, а дали десятичное значение от того, что стоит  после `%`. Хотя надо заметить, что функция chr сделает то же самое

Comment: @Mike, это ж вроде шестнадцатиричное значение? типа: name=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81

Comment: Ну так hex же из шестнадеричиного десятичное делает

Comment: Кстати я понял что у вас наверное не так. Эта же строка декодирует значение параметра. А надо такой же строкой декодировать еще имя параметра

Comment: всё понял, всем спасибо!! ну, как всем... Pink Tux'у и Mike'y =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё это ручное декодирование `GET` и `POST` никому не нужно уже лет 20 как. Более того, в нём будет столько подводных камней и граблей, что устанете изобретать велосипеды.

Если вы нашли какой-то руководство по CGI, где это рекомендуют - выбросьте его на помойку и забудьте. Раз так хочется возиться именно с CGI (в XXI веке-то...), то посмотрите хотя бы на модуль [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI), он специально для того и предназначен.

Вот как раз пример:

> когда я вывожу атрибут name элемента формы в perl-скрипте

Выводите-то вы неправильно в принципе. Вы должны получить на выходе массив, в котором содержатся все отмеченные элементы. А при вашем ручном разборе получите совсем не то. Модуль CGI же с такими вещами справляется на ура.

> делится на рез-ат функции pack?

При чём тут деление? Речь идёт о замене:

```
$value =~ s/ЧТО_МЕНЯЕМ/НА_ЧТО_МЕНЯЕМ/как_именно;
```

Модификатор `e` в части `как_меняем` говорит о том, что результат нужно предварительно обработать функцией `pack()` (которая в данном случае  декодирует последовательности вида `%XX` в нормальные символы). То есть в руководство по регулярным выражениям тоже стоит заглянуть, да и вообще - в какой-нибудь учебник по Perl. Только не настолько древний, в котором советуется ручная работа с параметрами форм.

Comment: спасибо за ответ)
понимаю, что это уже всё устаревшие технологии и вообще юзлесс, но я просто выполняю лабораторную работу с заданными условиями.

1. а что значит 'eg' в конце?
2. почему в маске два раза один и тот же набор? ([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])
3. почему перед маской стоит % ?
4. что за аргумент-функция hex с аргументом-переменной $1?

извиняюсь, что столько вопросов. ясно, что вам легче будет меня отослать читать гайды для даунов, но хотелось бы в данном случае пойти более легким для себя путём... хотя и сложным для вас.

Comment: @Anhk `e` на-что-меняем рассматривает как выполнимое выражение, т.е. вункцию pack вызывает, а не текст подставляет. `g` - глобально, меняет все такие места в строке. Без `g` поменяло бы только первое вхождение

Comment: @Anhk Википедия - "регулярные выражения". это надо прочесть в любом случае. А $1 - это первая подстрока которая в круглях скобках, т.е. две шестнадцетичные цифры, которые кстати как-раз этими кважратными скобками как списки символов заданы

Comment: @Anhk по поводу других непонятных мест - прямой путь такой, хотите узнать что такое hex, заходите в гугл, пишите "perl hex". все - вопрос решен и кстати я вам в коментарии к вашему вопросу написал что она делает

Comment: Кстати, я бы не сказал, что этот доисторический метод никуда не годится. Он наверняка из примера, который в цикле разбирает все параметры и кладет их в хеш.

Comment: @Mike, как сферическое декодирование - да, оно будет работать :) Но на практике к `URI::Escape` даже не приближается...

Comment: всё понял, всем спасибо!!
ну, как всем...
Pink Tux'у и Mike'y =)

Comment: @PinkTux Конечно не приближается, сам автор URI::escape пишет в описании функции unescape, что делает то же самое, что как раз вот такая регулярка только на 40-700% медленнее, чем регулярка. И пишет, что если надо менять много значений лучше используйте регулярку :)

Comment: хотя вот последний вопрос. массивы начинаются с символа '@', но в примере я встретил такую конструкцию:
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair); 
по смыслу понимаю, что это некое подобие массива. но хтоелось бы услышать конкретнее. split я понимаю )

Comment: @Anhk В круглых скобках - это списки, списки и массивы это разные вещи. split возвращает список который присваивается переменным из левого списка. Вы если объявляете и заполняете массив пишите @a=(1,2,3). обратите внимание на круглые скобки - это список - он преобразуется в массив. так же и наоборот ($a,$b,$c)=@a - первые 3 значения из массива окажутся в переменных

Comment: @Anhk вот это http://citforum.ru/internet/perl_tut/dat.shtml прочитайте